# Android L AVD is in black screen for ever while starting device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-5.0-lollipop

I just updated Android L SDK preview and created a new AVD
[image]

getting start up black screen for ever while starting my device
[image]

any one help me resolve this issue

Comment: Arm images are slooooooooooooooooooooow. So with that big of a resolution you will have to wait for a long time before anything happens. Pick a x86 image instead.

Comment: You are correct. I was waiting for more than hour no luck i could see only black screen

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable "Use host GPU" and see how it goes.